# Django - Reusing HTML snippets from multiple, different templates

Tags: html, django, templates

In my Django, is there a way to reuse HTML blocks from different sources? I know that there is a way to inherit HTML from a base template but what is there a way to get HTML from two or more sources?

Let's say that I wanted to grab a template that only contains a table and another template that only contains a navigation bar and place that on top of the base HTML. How would I go about doing that? Let's also make the assumption that template with the table and the template with the navigation bar has variable tags like `{{variable}}`.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Grammar.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just use `{% include "path/to/partial.html" %}` to achieve this.

One example from Django document:

```
{% include "name_snippet.html" with person="Jane" greeting="Hello" %}
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#include

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I am looking for.